# search in a pytables array

Tags: python, arrays, search, multidimensional-array, pytables

I have a multidimensional array stored in pytables.
how do I perform a search on it?
For example: I like to do a search to return a dimension of the array in which the sum of all values ​​of this dimension were greater than 10

Thanks